# rails - How to refactor this method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I got a little bit of a challenge but I don't know where to start. Long story short, I'm trying to make a method that will automatically translate a record from its model via Deepl or Google Translate.

I've got something working but I want to refactor it so it gets more versatile:

```
def translate
  texts = [self.title_fr, self.desc_fr, self.descRequirements_fr, self.descTarget_fr, self.descMeet_fr, self.descAdditional_fr]
  
  translations = DeepL.translate texts, 'FR', 'EN'

  self.update(title_en: translations[0], descRequirements_en: translations[2], descTarget_en: translations[3], descMeet_en: translations[4], descAdditional_en: translations[5])
end
```

Hopefully this is self explanatory.

I would love to have a method/concern working like such :

```
def deeplTranslate(record, attributes)
  // Code to figure out
end
```

and use it like such : `deeplTranslate(post, ['title', 'desc', 'attribute3'])`. And that will translate the attributes and save the translated attributes to the database in `en` language.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can point me to a valid direction to go towards.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I actually managed to create an auto translate method for active record :

```
def deeplTranslate(record, attributes, originLang, newLang)
  keys = attributes.map{|a| record.instance_eval(a + "_#{originLang}")}
  
  translations = DeepL.translate keys, originLang, newLang

  new_attributes = Hash.new
  attributes.each_with_index do |a, i|
    new_attributes[a + "_#{newLang}"] = translations[i].text
  end

  record.update(new_attributes)
end
```

Maybe it can get cleaner... But it's working : )